# Playwright Python can't access iframe content in Firefox

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to access iframe content, but the content is empty when I check the content in Playwright while using Firefox browser.

Here is an example of the iframe:

```
<iframe src="./cf_files/normal.html" allow="cross-origin-isolated" id="cf-chl-widget-3stgj" tabindex="0" title="Widget containing a test checkbox" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 65px;"></iframe>
```

Here is the input element I need from the embedded HTMl of the iframe:

```
<label class="ctp-checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox"><span class="mark"></span><span class="ctp-label">Click here</span></label>
```

When I inspect it via dev tools I can see the embedded HTML #document and when I expand it it has all the information I need, although via Playwright I don't see that information.

It works with chromium, but not with firefox.

Here is sample code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from time import sleep

def main():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        # Select browser type
        browser_type = playwright.firefox
        browser = browser_type.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()

        # Navigate to the webpage containing the iframe
        page.goto('https://www.google.com')


        # Switch to the iframe
        iframe_locator = page.frame_locator('[title="Widget containing checkbox test"]')
        
        # Perform actions within the iframe
        checkbox = iframe_locator.locator('input[type="checkbox"]')
        sleep(5)
        checkbox.click()

        print(f"Page content - {page.content()}")
        # Close the browser
        browser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why it works with chromium but not with firefox?

Regarding just using chromium, for certain reasons, I need to use firefox browser.

Also, with both browsers page.content() does not show iframe embedded HTML content, even though it successfully clicks the checkbox with chromium.

Comment: Can you share your actual URL and selectors as a [mcve]? Is it really google.com? `sleep(5)` is a race condition--better to wait for an actual predicate.

Comment: Well, I know this is Cloudflare's turnstile challenge. The question is have you managed to solve it? I'm in the same issue right now :)